# In a dictionary where keys are tuples, remove all keys that does not have a specific value in specific positions

Tags: python, tuples

I have a dictionary where each key is a tuple ength N. In each position there is either a string or an empty string.

```
d = {('Word A','Word B','','','Word C',....) : 50,
     ('Word F', '','','',....,'Word H') : 10, 
     ....
     }
```

I have a category dictionary containing indexes, if a key in `d` has an empty string at every position specified by the indexes, it belongs to the category. A key can belong to multiple categories.

```
category_dictionary= { 'Category A':[1,2,3] , 'Category B' : [0,3,4] , .... }
```

In this example, the second entry in d `('Word F', '','','',....,'Word H')` belongs to `Category A` since it has an empty string in position 1,2 and 3.

I want to remove all keys in `d` which **do not belong to any category**. What would be an efficient way of doing this? Here is code which is working but is slow.

```
    filtered_list = []
    for current_tuple in list(d.keys()):
        keep_tuple = False
        for category,idxs in category_dictionary.items():
            all_idxs_empty = True
            for idx in idxs:
                if current_tuple[idx] != '':
                    all_idxs_empty = False
            if all_idxs_empty:
                filtered_list.append(current_tuple)
                break

     d_filter = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in filtered_list}
```

What would be a more efficient way of doing this? If I have M keys, T categories and the maximum length is U, the complexity is between complexity `[O(M*T),O(M*T*U)]`

Is there a way to reduce the complexity somehow?

***Example data with N = 3 and 2 categories***

```
d = {('A','','B','H') : 10, 
     ('','','','H') : 20,
     ('','','F','T') : 30,
     ('A','C','G','') : 0
     }

category_dictionary = { 'Category A':[0,1],'Category B' :[3]}
```

**Expected output**

```
d_filter = {('','','','H'): 20,
           ('','','F','T'):30,
           ('A','C','G','') : 0
           }
```

Comment: Define "very slow," and how much faster you think it should be.

Comment: can you break after `all_idxs_empty = False`?

Comment: I added the current complexity, anything faster than the current approach is good.

Comment: Yes you can, since if all_idxs_empty = False, that means that the tuple belongs to atleast 1 category, and should be saved.

Comment: @kspr so add a `break` and see the impact

Comment: Just a note, earlier in your question you seem to be indexing strings starting at 1, and later starting at 0.

Comment: You can't reduce the *complexity* (imagine if *everything* should get filtered out), but (as others have suggested) you can reduce the *time*.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Thanks, I will edit it.

Comment: `for current_tuple in list(d.keys())` doubles the iterations over `d` (or at least does *some* unnecessary work), just use `for current_tuple in d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def f(tuple_, category_dictionary):
    l=[i for i in range(len(tuple_)) if tuple_[i]=='']
    return any([set(k)-set(l)==set() for k in category_dictionary.values()])

m=list(d.keys())    
for i in m:
    if not f(i, category_dictionary):
        del d[i]
```

Comment: Hi, this would throw "Dictionary Changed Size During Iteration" runtime error.

Comment: Sorry, for that, this happened because m was a copy of d.keys() and was updated simultaneoysly. I saved it as a list, it should work now

Comment: By the way, I think you should change set(k)-set(l) == set() to set(k).issubset(set(l)) since the values not specified by the category set can have whatever value.

Comment: set(k)-set(l) == set() is equal to set(k).issubset(set(l))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is faster, but this is simpler.

```py
filtered_list = []
category_set = [set(x) for x in category_dictionary.values()]

for current_tuple in list(d.keys()):
    #in_category = [i for i,x in enumerate(current_tuple) if x=='']  in category_dictionary.values()
    current_set = {i for i,x in enumerate(current_tuple) if x==''}
    in_category = any([set.issubset(x, current_set) for x in category_set])
    if in_category:
        filtered_list.append(current_tuple)

d_filter = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in filtered_list}
d_filter
```

Comment: Hi, it is not a mistake, it fulfills the empty string being in position [0,1] so it does not matter what the value in the other positions are

Comment: I made changes to reflect that you want to check if any of the `category_dictionary.values`  is subset of a `current_tuple`.